# Event log directories with boost

Tags: c++, logging, boost

I want to log into the windows event log with C++.
I tried boost and added simple logs.
But I want to create a new directory in the event viewer and log into that directory.

How can I do that with boost event logger or another way (other than boost)?

I added a screenshot of the event viewer that shows the part I want to add a directory and logs in it.[image]

Here is my event log initialization method.

```
void LogHelper::InitEventLogger(LogLevel minLogLevel)
{
    try
    {
        // Create an event log sink
        typedef sinks::synchronous_sink< sinks::simple_event_log_backend > sink_t;
        boost::shared_ptr< sink_t > sink = boost::make_shared< sink_t>();

        sink->set_filter(expr::attr<LogLevel>("Severity") >= minLogLevel);
        sink->set_formatter(expr::stream << expr::attr< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp") << " : " << expr::smessage);

        // We'll have to map our custom levels to the event log event types
        sinks::event_log::custom_event_type_mapping< LogLevel > mapping("Severity");
        mapping[LogLevel::info] = sinks::event_log::info;
        mapping[LogLevel::warning] = sinks::event_log::warning;
        mapping[LogLevel::error] = sinks::event_log::error;

        sink->locked_backend()->set_event_type_mapper(mapping);
        logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
    }
    catch (std::exception & ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: read the docs, like http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sink_backends.html#log.detailed.sink_backends.event_log?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: I have already read the docs, but I coudn't find a way to create new directory and log into it.